# Displaying the same object in two different sections of UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout / UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, ios13

I have a `UICollectionView` where I lay out two sections (one horizontally scrolling, one vertically scrolling), using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`. I've combined this with usage of `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` in order to cut down on inconsistencies. However, I've run into a dilemma.

The two sections don't necessarily share the same cell objects, but sometimes there will be a cell in each section that is based off the same object (as each section provides a different context to the object in question). `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` requires every object in the collection to have some sort of unique identifier, and apparently this identifier cannot be shared across sections. Is there a way that I can create a cell in each section based off the same object?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue recently. My solution was to wrap the data objects in an `Item` struct and calculate the identifier by combing the hashes of the section and item.

```
/// A data source section.
struct Section: Hashable {
    let title: String
    let id: Int

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.id)
    }
}

/// A data source item.
struct Item: Hashable {
    let section: Section
    let object: MyObject

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.section)
        hasher.combine(self.object)
    }
}
```

Comment: followed the same approach but it requires recreating the `collectionViewLayout` with a defined number of available sections before applying the new datasource, still looking for a better solution with requires less booking keeping but thanks for this answer was a great starting point!